# Title band with the full page size in a cover page

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm trying to create a cover page for my *JasperReports*'s report, but the information from the second page gets into my cover. A solution I've thought was to make the title band filling the full page, but when I try to put a value greater than 734, I get an error. I'm a kind of lost here, and I maybe there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. The following expression was add the band to check when printing:

`new Boolean($V{PAGE_NUMBER}.intValue()!=1)`